# Procedure with transaction returns an error 1746

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

This is my procedure

```
use my_database;
drop procedure if exists sel_upd_ports;
delimiter $$
create procedure sel_upd_ports()
begin
    drop temporary table if exists oneone;
    start transaction;
    create temporary table oneone as (select id,tt from table where status=0 limit 10 for update);
    update table a join oneone b on a.id=b.id set status=1;
    commit;
    select * from oneone;
    drop temporary table oneone;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

this is what I need:

1. it has to be a procedure
2. update+select queries should be working in transaction, so my application can be concurrent
3. procedure should return a result set

this procedure works, but I can't get rid of an error

```
ERROR 1746 (HY000): Can't update table 'table' while 'oneone' is being created.
```

and it goes away as soon as i delete a lock "for update".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation:

> [13.2.9 SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)
>
> ...
>
> In addition, you cannot use **`FOR UPDATE`** as part of the [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) in a
>   statement such as [`CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT ... FROM old_table ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html). (If you attempt to do so, the statement is rejected with the
>   error **Can't update table '*old_table*' while '*new_table*' is being
>   created.**) This is a change in behavior from MySQL 5.5 and earlier,
>   which permitted [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) statements to make changes in
>   tables other than the table being created.
>
> ...

See MySQL 5.6 Release Notes:

> [Changes in MySQL 5.6.2 (2011-04-11, Developer Milestone) :: Bugs
>   Fixed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-2.html#mysqld-5-6-2-bug)
>
> - ***Incompatible Change; Replication:*** It is no longer possible to issue a [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) statement which changes any tables other than the table being created. Any such statement is not executed and
>     instead fails with an error.
>
>   One consequence of this change is that **`FOR UPDATE`** may no longer be
>     used at all with the [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) portion of a [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html).
>
>   This means that, prior to upgrading from a previous release, you
>     should rewrite any [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) statements that cause
>     changes in other tables so that the statements no longer do so.
>
>   This change also has implications for statement-based replication
>     between a MySQL 5.6 (or later slave) and a master running a previous
>     version of MySQL. In such a case, if a [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html)
>     statement on the master that causes changes in other tables succeeds
>     on the master, the statement nonetheless fails on the slave, causing
>     replication to stop. To keep this from happening, you should either
>     use row-based replication, or rewrite the offending statement before
>     running it on the master. (Bug #11749792, Bug #11745361, Bug #39804,
>     Bug #55876)
>
>   References: See also: Bug #47899.